# My application has no logo when my friends download it

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, icons

I recently created an android app and I put it on the play store.
I created an icon for this application, which I put in the android code and on the information sheet of the play store, but recently my friends told me that when they were downloading my app, it didn’t have a logo.
They had the green android logo.

Here’s how I added my logo to the app.

In AndroidManifest.xml :
I add in "application" marker :

```
android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo_qui_a_soif_blanc"`
```

I also add my logo to my "Drawable" file and right click on "res" folder, then "new", and "image asset" and I add my image here.

Have I missed something or not?

Comment: have you added  android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon_new"  this??

Comment: I will try that, thank you for your comment. I'll come back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `android:icon="@drawable/logo"` in your manifest along with `android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"`

Comment: Thank that Works !

Comment: Hey, good to know it worked! Could you accept the answer as right?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue in android studio. I suggest you delete that logo and refresh the whole application and then try again. Same thing happened to me as well and it worked for me.